# how to add to the list of dropdowns, the distance between them?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget, I have a dropdown in mine depending on the amount of data in the map. But the problem is these dropdowns appear very close to each other, is it possible to add the distance between them ??
Список дропдаунів вмене знадоиться в змінній  "list ".

```
  Widget _buildAdditionFields(SimpleOrderStates state) {
if (state.isAdditionsProgress) {
  return const Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(Margins.small),
    child: PlatformProgressIndicator(),
  );
} else {

  var containsVariants = state.additionEntity?.hasVariants ?? false;
  var name = state.additionEntity?.name ?? '';
  var options = state.additionEntity
      ?.getAddition(0)
      ?.dropdownItems;
  print(state.additionEntity?.selectedVariants);
     var list = state.additionEntity?.selectedVariants
      .mapIndexed(
          (index, addition) =>
          _buildDropdownField(
              text: '',
              enabled: true,
              progress: false,
              dropdownOptions: [],
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
              applySelected: true,
              action: SvgPicture.asset(Img.dropdownArrow),
              labelText: addition!["additionName"],
              dropdownItemSelected: (item) {
                BlocProvider.of<SimpleOrderBloc>(context).add(
                    SimpleOrderDropdownMenuAdditionItemSelectedEvent(item));
              },
              textChanged: (text) {}
          ),


     ).toList();

     if(state.next != null){
       list?.add(_buildDropdownField(
           text: '',
           enabled: true,
           progress: false,
           dropdownOptions:options ?? [],
           focusNode: FocusNode(),
           applySelected: true,
           action: SvgPicture.asset(Img.dropdownArrow),
           labelText: name,
           dropdownItemSelected: (item) {
             BlocProvider.of<SimpleOrderBloc>(context).add(
                 SimpleOrderDropdownMenuAdditionItemSelectedEvent(item));
           },
           textChanged: (text) {}
       ),);

     }

  return Column(
    children: list ?? [],
  );
 }
```

Comment: can you add some screens? what is your error and what you are expecting?

Comment: @Prabhakaran I added a screen, see how close ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your drop-down widget with padding. in your case you need

> padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(4)

```
list?.add(
  Container(
     padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
     child: _buildDropdownField(
       text: '',
       enabled: true,
       progress: false,
       dropdownOptions:options ?? [],
       focusNode: FocusNode(),
       applySelected: true,
       action: SvgPicture.asset(Img.dropdownArrow),
       labelText: name,
       dropdownItemSelected: (item) {
         BlocProvider.of<SimpleOrderBloc>(context).add(
            SimpleOrderDropdownMenuAdditionItemSelectedEvent(item));
       },
       textChanged: (text) {})));
```